# Passing Input Data to a JS File

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

I am attempting to pass data from a html input to a js file. Specifically, I am trying to send a url to a js file to be used.

I have attempted to so with a `document.getElementById` command that is linked to the input but I have not seen success. Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**My HTML (Form with input and button)**

```
<html>

 <head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="./bin/pageCapture.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <form id="form" method="post" action="screenshot.php">

    <input type="text" name="sitelink" id="sitelink" placeholder="Enter Link">
    <br>

   <div class="display1">
     <button class="button1" id="button" onmouseover="changeColor()" onmouseout="colorBack()">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </form>

</body>



</html>
```

**JS File (*var url* is how I am currently trying to pass the data)**

```
 var url = document.getElementById('sitelink').value;

 var webpage = require('webpage');

 var page = webpage.create();



 page.open(url, function(status) {
  console.log(page['objectName']);
  console.log(page['title']);
  console.log(page['url']);


 console.log("Status: " + status);
   if(status === "success") {
 page.render('screenCapture1.jpeg', {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
  }

 phantom.exit();
 });
```

**PHP (Form output)**

```
<html>

 <?php

  $sitelink = $_POST['sitelink'];

  $cmd = ' ./bin/phantomjs';
  $cmd.= ' ./bin/pageCapture.js';

  putenv('PATH=./bin/');

  exec($cmd.' 2>&1', $output);

  $imagelink = 'screenCapture1.jpeg';

  ?>

  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Your screenshot:</h2>
  <img class="screenshot" src=<?php echo $imagelink ?>>

 </html>
```

As you can see, the functionality is pretty simple. Enter a url, click submit, and the form should return a screenshot. However, the url from the input is not being passed to the js file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *However, the url from the input is not being passed to the js file.* what is actually happening ? what do you see when you `console.log(url)` ?

Comment: You are confusing client-side and server-side JavaScript. pageCapture.js doesn't execute in the browser.

Comment: @Peter pageCapture.js does execute in browser. It executes based on the PHP code above.

Comment: Unless you are doing something really unusual PHP doesn't run in the browser and consequently neither does phantomjs.

Comment: @TowkirAhmed `console.log(url)` returns nothing